# Strategy Open long exactly at market open (9:30 NYSE)

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Thanks for reading and maybe helping me out.

I am trying to create a strategy script that enters a long position at market Open price on a security Exactly at 09:30 (like a market buy at 09:30) However it always enters the long the next candle. So 09:31 on the 1m.Is there a way to get the long at the exact daily open price?

```
//@version=2
// This script is a tradingbot that buys NYSE:GOLD based on the performance of TVC:GOLD
strategy(title="Barrick Gold Buy, overlay=true, process_orders_on_close = true")

// Define the symbols
gold = "TVC:GOLD"

// Get the close prices for the previous trading day
prev_close_gold = security(gold, 'D', close[1])

// Get the current close prices
close_gold = security(gold, '1', close)

// Check if the current close price is greater than the previous close price
if close_gold > prev_close_gold
    // Check if it is 09:30
    if hour(time) == 09 and minute(time) == 30
        // If it is, then buy NYSE:GOLD
        strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long, 1000)

// Check if NYSE:GOLD is in a long position
if strategy.position_size > 0
    // If it is, then take profit when the price reaches 20 cents higher
    strategy.exit("SELL", "BUY", strategy.position_size, profit = 20, loss = 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the `process_orders_on_close` argument to `true`.

You actually have this in your code, however, you forgot to end your title with a `"`.

So, your title is actually: `Barrick Gold Buy, overlay=true, process_orders_on_close = true`

Fix it like below and it will work fine.

```
strategy(title="Barrick Gold Buy", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close = true)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for fixing that :-) However as the code says it starts at the first bar but enters at the close. This was the best I could come up with. However. I would really like the first bar and the open price for the entry. Like you put a market order immediately at opening of the stock. So Gold is up compared to the previous day and then market buy Barrick at 9:30